# How to protect from UV radiations and sunburns using elements found in nature?

Tags: camping, forests, uv-protection

Is is possible to avoid sunburns and block UV radiations without using industrial suncream, but using elements found in nature(plants, mud, etc.)?

Comment: Nature where in the world?

Comment: Check this question; it may answer yours. 
         https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20247/are-there-any-natural-materials-found-in-the-wild-that-can-be-used-as-an-effecti/20257#20257

Comment: Dense forests are perfectly fine as sunblocker :-)